# How can you find all the links between files?

Tags: php, file, visual-studio-code, ide, atom-editor

I have to work on a folder that has multiple subfolders and all in all there are over 150 files. This includes php, css, js, and image files. My focus is on php.

Quite frankly, I am a little overwhelmed. 
How can I have an overview of which files import functions/classes from another file. That way I can see the connections between different files in this forest and allow me to better navigate through this jungle.

I tried printing ***tree*** in cmd to get an idea of the file structure:

```
├───core                                
│   ├───assets                          
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───extra
```

etc.

I went quickly through most of the files and took notes what they are. My problem is that going through over 10,000 lines of code to find the connections will take me forever. Are there any tools in the IDE that help or do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: File structure should be the easy part. If it isn't obvious at first sight then you're probably out of luck because you've inherited a terrible mess of spaghetti. There're tools to generate graphs or documentation from *classes* (e.g. [phpDocumentor](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor)) but they can be totally useless if the code is not object-oriented.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the stack trace of induced errors as add on information.